# PHP imagick - non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4469

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

PHP version:

```
PHP 7.4.20 (cli) (built: Jun 28 2021 22:14:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

imagick version:

```
/var/www/html # php -i | grep imagick
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-imagick.ini,
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.5.1
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
imagick.allow_zero_dimension_images => 0 => 0
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.set_single_thread => 1 => 1
imagick.shutdown_sleep_count => 10 => 10
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0
```

Relevant php code:

```
        $img = new \Imagick();
        $img->setResolution(300, 380);
        $img->readImage($img2Fake);
        $img->setFormat('png24');

        $bg = new \Imagick();

        $bg->newImage(300, 380, new \ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));

        $draw = new \ImagickDraw();

        $draw->setFillColor(new \ImagickPixel("#ede717"));
        $draw->setStrokeColor(new \ImagickPixel('#ede717'));

        $bgx2 = 63.5 * (float)$avgRating;
        $draw->rectangle(24, 0, $bgx2, 380);

        $bg->drawImage($draw);
        $bg->compositeImage($img, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
        $bg->setImageFormat('jpg');

        $strDraw = new \ImagickDraw();
        $strDraw->setFillColor(new \ImagickPixel('#555'));
        $strDraw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
        $strDraw->setFontSize('32');
        $strDraw->setFontWeight(900);
        $strDraw->annotation(150, 135, $ratingText);
        $strDraw->setFontSize('20');
        $strDraw->setFontWeight(200);
        $strDraw->annotation(150, 168, $avgRating . ' / 5,0');
        $strDraw->setFontSize('18');
        $strDraw->setFontWeight(200);
        $strDraw->annotation(150, 194, number_format($count, 0, ',', '.') . ' Bewertungen');
        $bg->drawImage($strDraw);
```

Exception:

```
ImagickException: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4469
#6 /var/www/html/src/pp/WidgetBundle/Lib/WidgetRenderer.php(95): Imagick::drawimage
#5 /var/www/html/src/pp/WidgetBundle/Lib/WidgetRenderer.php(95): pp\WidgetBundle\Lib\WidgetRenderer::renderWidget
#4 /var/www/html/src/pp/WidgetBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php(30): pp\WidgetBundle\Controller\DefaultController::renderAction
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::handleRaw
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::handle
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(200): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::handle
#0 /app.php(162): null
```

Relevant Dockerfile part:

```
FROM registry.var-lab.com/php/php:7.4.20-fpm-alpine

...

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS imagemagick-dev libtool \
    && export CFLAGS="$PHP_CFLAGS" CPPFLAGS="$PHP_CPPFLAGS" LDFLAGS="$PHP_LDFLAGS" \
    && pecl install imagick-3.5.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .imagick-runtime-deps imagemagick \
    && apk del .phpize-deps
```

It has worked without using docker, but with the same PHP version "directy" installed on an Ubuntu 16.x machine.

I've tried to use another version of imagick in the Docker container, but it does not solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was: There are no fonts installed in the docker-container by default: `Imagick::queryFonts()` returns an empty array.

The solution is:

Add some default fonts to the docker-container (it works with that, but in my code no font is explicitly set):

```
RUN apk add --no-cache msttcorefonts-installer && update-ms-fonts && fc-cache -f
```

See also https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/543